# How many computer instructions are involved in a Python print statement?

Tags: python, performance, printing

I ask this question because when a loop is debugged with repeated print statements, it slows down the program much more that I would have originally expected.  I have gotten used to this, but now I am curious as to the technical reasons why this would be the case? It seems to me that the various calculations and assignings of variables would be more expensive than outputting strings.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with CPU instructions; your terminal is much slower than the CPU.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers. I'm self taught and my education is just beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite a few, but another important (or even the most important) bottleneck is unrelated to the CPU: I/O overhead. Once the bytecode instruction(s) have been dispatched and all arguments have been converted to strings, a function is called to write those strings to `sys.stdout`. Depending on your system and how you run the program, this may be:

1. A file on disk
2. A pipe from a terminal emulator
3. Some Python objects that capture the output (this is what IDLE does IIRC) to do who-knows-what with it (capture it, put it into a GUI, etc).

In case #1, disk I/O is involved and that's easily an order of magnitude slower than writing to RAM. And RAM is already awfully slow compared to today's CPUs. As noted in a comment, this is less of an issue due to extensive buffering by the OS and by Python, but still takes time to issue the write and (depending on implementation details I don't know much about) it may still take some time if someone flushes any buffers prematurely.

In case #2, everything remains in memory, but it's still a system call, some copying, and the other end has to read it and do something with it for you to notice (e.g. render it in a fancy terminal emulator with an anti-aliased font, which is a complex task itself). Less of an issue as it can happen concurrently, but it nevertheless places load on the CPU.

In case #3, all bets are off. It may hash the output with bcrypt and send it to the moon for all we know. Do you happen to use IDLE? I recall a complaint that IDLE was (is?) *very* slow with redirecting output, especially with lots of tine pieces. It has to capture the output, concatenate it with the output so far, and let Tkinter render that.

Answer (score 2):

A huge, huge, ***huge*** number, especially if the output is visible on screen, such as in a terminal emulator window on a modern multitasking system.

Firstly, if you’re outputting numbers in decimal, there’s a divmod for each digit, which is a relatively expensive operation compared to, say, adding. (If you output in hexadecimal, it can be a bit cheaper, as each digit can be extracted using shifting and masking only.) If you output floats, there’s some more calculation involved; with dates and times, there’s months of various lengths, leap years, leap seconds, DST, and timezones all to be considered.

But that’s all just calculation and logic, so it’s dwarfed by what’s to come.

Next Python has to send the output text to the terminal for display, which means the operating system has to step in to transfer the data through a buffer, then wake up the other process. The terminal process scans its input for control sequences to move the cursor or change colours. Then a text renderer scans the text for characters that need special handling: maybe there’s some combining accents to be applied, or some right-to-left script that needs to be rearranged for display.

Once the text is laid out, the terminal tells the window manager which area of its window needs to be redrawn, and the window manager checks whether it’s visible – it might be minimized or hidden behind another window. The terminal is told which area actually needs painting, and finally draws the text, in its proper font and colours, kerning and antialiasing. Does the window have a cool-looking transparent background? That has to be merged in too.

Depending on the windowing system, the pixels could then go on another trip through operating system buffers to a compositing manager, which actually draws the window contents onto the screen, taking into account window transparency.

FInally, the pixels arrive on screen, where they barely have time to be seen before being swept away by their millions of successors, as you watch the output streaming past far too fast to read.

It’s amazing how much work our computers do for us.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of CPU instructions, at least not the CPU instructions in your Python program. When you do a `print` with a terminal emulator (command window) as output, the string to be printed is copied into a kernel buffer, then to the terminal process's memory. The overhead is in the context switching (both processes doing system calls, i.e. jumping into kernel mode) and the copying of the string in memory.

Comment: Actually, usually IO on disk tends to feel faster, because, unless you `sync` all the time/output tons of data, it is heavily buffered, and the OS can take care of flushing the buffer while your program is doing other stuff. IO on console, on the other hand, cannot have but the lightest buffering, otherwise the user won't promptly see what the program printed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: you're right, I forgot that terminals are usually line buffered. Removed the bit about disks so as not to confuse the OP.